# Xamarin Forms (iOS) - Change Transparency of Keyboard Background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, picker, custom-renderer

I have a Xamarin Forms project, where I've created a custom renderer for a Picker and Entry (both of which bring up a keyboard when focused). I want to customize a couple things about the keyboard. You can see that the background of a keyboard (in a Picker or Entry when focused) is semi-transparent:

[image]

and

[image]

**How do I control the transparency of the background?**

One thing I'm confused on is in my custom renderer, how to affect the Picker or Entry *field* vs. the *Keyboard* that comes up when you focus on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work:

```
var cl = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);
t.BackgroundColor = cl;
```

Where t = YourPickerView or PickerRenderer.